# MultiResourcePartitioner - Multiple Partitions Loading Same Resource

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I'm using local partitioning in spring batch to write xml files to the database. I have already split the original file to smaller files and i have used MultiResourcePartitioner to process each one of them as each file will be processed by one thread. I'm getting **a violation of primary Key constraint** error i don't know how to deal with this issue

**List of files**

[image]

**The partitionner**

```
@Bean
public Partitioner partitioner1(){
    MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
    Resource[] resources;
    try {
        resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("file:src/main/resources/data/*.xml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I/O problems when resolving the input file pattern.",e);
    }
    partitioner.setResources(resources);
    return partitioner;
}
```

**The StaxEventItemReader using XML file as an input for the reader**

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public StaxEventItemReader<Customer> CustomerItemReader()  {

        XStreamMarshaller unmarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();

        Map<String, Class> aliases = new HashMap<>();
        aliases.put("customer", Customer.class);

        unmarshaller.setAliases(aliases);

        StaxEventItemReader<Customer> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();

        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("data/customerOutput1-25000.xml"));

        reader.setFragmentRootElementName("customer");
        reader.setUnmarshaller(unmarshaller);

        return reader;
    }
```

**The JdbcBatchItemWriter (writing to the database)**

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();


        itemWriter.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        itemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO NEW_CUSTOMER VALUES (:id, :firstName, :lastName, :birthdate)");
        itemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider());
        itemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();

        return itemWriter;
    }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reader has this line, which causes all the partitions to load the same file:

```
reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("data/customerOutput1-25000.xml"));
```

It should instead take the resource from the Step Execution Context. You can access the execution context either in the `open()` method using the `ItemStream` interface or the `beforeStep()` method of the `StepExectionListener` interface. A bit of personal preference here, but I generally thing using `ItemStream` is the "better" solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply,I solved the problem by injecting the value of ressource path in the reader :
 @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['inputKeyName']}") do you think using the ItemStream interface is better ?

Comment: So most `ItemReader`s that read a `Resource` will implement `ItemStream`. As long as you call `setResource()` on the writer before their `open()` method is called you're fine. There's a number of ways to do this, but I typically choose a delegate pattern where my custom reader also implements `ItemStream` and then in its `open()` method will first get the `Resource` and then call `delegate.setResource(resource), delegate.open(executionContext)`. Again, up to you, but that's what I prefer to do.

Comment: does this actually working withou persisting metadata tables that have executionContext params) to database ?